# Changing input so in can take any length of string, problems with output

Tags: java, methods

Currently I have a method that asks user for an input string but only outputs the first 16 characters! The method is supposed to take in any length of string then output the characters in 4x4 blocks after it does the following: first row remains the same. Shift the second row one position to the left, then shifts the third row two positions to the left. Finally, shift the fourth row three positions to the left. As of now it will only output the first 4x4 block

Also I am not sure how I can change the method so it doesnt ask for user input
I would like it to use a given string like:

String text = shiftRows("WVOGJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFOPMO");

"WVOGJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFOPMO" is the given encrypted string I would like to use. but without asking for user input..I keep getting errors and incorrect outputs..please show how I might fix this

code I am using:

```
public class shiftRows {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] input= new String[4];

    String[] output= new String[4];

    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    String inputStr = sc.next();


    for (int i = 0, n = 0; i < 4; i++, n+=4) {
        input[i] = inputStr.substring(0+n, 4+n);
    }
    // -

    output[0] = input[0];
    for(int i=1; i<4; i++)
    {
        output[i] = Shift(input[i],i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(output[i]);
    }

}

public static String Shift(String str, int shiftNum)
{
    char[] out = new char[4];
    if(shiftNum==1)
    {
        out[0]=str.charAt(1);
        out[1]=str.charAt(2);
        out[2]=str.charAt(3);
        out[3]=str.charAt(0);
    }
    if(shiftNum==2)
    {
        out[0]=str.charAt(2);
        out[1]=str.charAt(3);
        out[2]=str.charAt(0);
        out[3]=str.charAt(1);
    }
    if(shiftNum==3)
    {
        out[0]=str.charAt(3);
        out[1]=str.charAt(0);
        out[2]=str.charAt(1);
        out[3]=str.charAt(2);
    }
    return new String(out);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by shift to the left? Do you want this type of output TEST HEYH IHOW AREY OU

Comment: You should stop just posting your homework here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good way to do it :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class shiftRows {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputStr = "WVOGJTXQHUHXICWYYMGHTRKQHQPWKYVGLPYSPWGOINTOFOPMO";

        for (int i = 0 ; i < inputStr.length() ; i++){
            System.out.print(inputStr.charAt(i));
            if ((i + 1)%4 == 0) System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to stock it into a `String`, just concatenate at each loop and add a `"\n"` each time the if test is valid.